# Lost keystore android

Tags: android, keystore

Eu perdi minha keystore android e não consigo atualizar o aplicativo.
Como recuperar minha chave, não estava cadastrado no programa de armazenamento?

Comment: Se você perde a chave de assinatura você pode tentar entrar em contato com o GOOGLE, porém, a resposta que obtive é que seria necessário a submissão de outro app com a nova chave.

Answer (score 1):

O texto abaixo foi tirado da pagina de [Ajuda do Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9061737?hl=pt-BR), me parece se seu caso é o segundo *(Apps não inscritos na Assinatura de apps do Google Play)*.

<sub>em 10/12/2019 ↓</sub>

> ## Apps inscritos na Assinatura de apps do Google Play
>
> Caso você tenha inscrito seu app na [Assinatura de apps do Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) e precise criar uma nova chave de upload, o proprietário da conta poderá [entrar em contato com nossa equipe de suporte](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs) para receber ajuda.
>
> Veja alguns motivos comuns para você precisar criar uma nova chave de upload:
>
> - A chave privada foi perdida ou comprometida.
> - Não foi criada uma chave de upload para um app existente.
>
> ## Apps não inscritos na Assinatura de apps do Google Play
>
> Se perder seu armazenamento de chaves, você precisará publicar um novo app com outro nome de pacote e outra chave. Recomendamos atualizar o app original para que os usuários conheçam o novo e cancelar a publicação para evitar downloads futuros.
>
> **Observação**: não podemos excluir apps nem permitir que vários deles tenham o mesmo nome de pacote.
>
> #### Saiba mais sobre certificados e armazenamentos de chaves
>
> Para ver informações detalhadas sobre certificados, armazenamentos de chaves e como fazer a assinatura do seu app, visite o [site para desenvolvedores Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#cert).